# mocking module library using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing test case for a react chat application, we are using amazon-connect-chatjs library for that so this library providing few apis like session.onConnectionEstablished and session.onMessage so on, in this apis we are writing few logic based on that component will render accordingly.
so I want to mock for example session.onConnectionEstablished  and pass inside that method or api so it pass through our logic that will render particular component and I will write test cases for  that component
which rendered , Any idea how to do this. please see the logic below

```
import 'amazon-connect-chatjs'
const chat = ()=>{
const [userName setUserName] = useState('')
/* initial setup to initiate amazon-connect-chatjs */
connect.ChatSession.setGlobalConfig({
  loggerConfig: { 
    logger: { 
      debug: (msg) => console.debug(msg), 
      info: (msg) => console.info(msg), 
      warn: (msg) => console.warn(msg), 
      error: (msg) => console.error(msg) 
    },
    level: connect.ChatSession.LogLevel.WARN, 
  },
  region: "us-east-1", 
});

  const customerChatSession = connect.ChatSession.create({
                       chatDetails: { // REQUIRED
                       contactId: "...", // REQUIRED
                       participantId: "...", // REQUIRED
                       participantToken: "...", // REQUIRED
  },
  options: { 
    region: "us-east-1",
   `connect.ChatSession.setGlobalConfig()`

  },
  type: connect.ChatSession.SessionTypes.CUSTOMER, // REQUIRED
});


customerChatSession.create().then((response)=>{
return response;
}
)

customerChatSession.onConnectionEstablished(()=>{
setLoaderMessage('connecting...')
setUserName('true')
})

{{userName && <MessageList>}}
```

}

Note: by giving mock data I can pass required details to chatjs library and I getting response from  `customerChatSession.create().then((response)=>{ return response; }`

but after that I kind of stuck how to mock
 `customerChatSession.onConnectionEstablished` and  pass through that method if it pass, it sets the useState which will render the component so i can test whether the component is rendering or not

I am not sure whether mocking is write approach or any other way to do this

Thanks

Comment: You should [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: updated the question with code